# Is ByteBuffer.getInt() blocking?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, blocking, bytebuffer

I'm willing to use a `ByteBuffer` to inter thread communication of JNI and C++. I couldn't find in the documentation whether ByteBuffer's `getInt()` is blocking or not. So, do I need to do something like:

```
if(byteBuffer.asIntBuffer().hasRemaining())
    byteBuffer.getInt();
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

or

```
byteBuffer.getInt();
```

will block so sleep is unnecessary?

Comment: It's not a stream, it doesn't wait for any input, it just reads a fixed memory location.

Comment: `ByteBuffer`s have no synchronization at all; they're not thread safe.

Comment: @Louis They're not atomic? What do you mean?

Comment: @quimnuss: No, they're not atomic.  `ByteBuffer` has no thread safety whatsoever.  If it's not documented, it's not there.

Comment: @zhong they're two threads, not two processes.

Comment: I think you have confused Buffers with Channels. Buffers are just some memory (that may be optimized for moving data to certain channels, like either native malloc'ed memory or memory mapped from some device or file). Channels are used to copy data to/from buffers, and they can indeed be blocking or non-blocking (and in the latter case signal a Selector when done).

Comment: there's no guarantee that putInt/getInt are atomic like read/write normal `int`.

Comment: What event would it block on? Not a real question.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getInt%28%29), if there aren't at least four bytes in the buffer, it will throw `BufferUnderflowException`. That suggests it doesn't block (as does the fact that the word "block" doesn't appear on its documentation page at all).

But note that your `sleep` solution won't work, because you're doing the `sleep` call **after** calling `getInt`, which will have already thrown an exception if there isn't enough data there yet. You need to ensure the buffer has at least four bytes in it *before* you call `getInt`.

Comment: yes, the actual code is longer. You're right the excerpt might be misleading. Fixed.